# Is it possible to start Hangouts Chrome extension window as a separate instance (like the app window)?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, google-chrome, google-hangouts, chrome-extension

[Hangouts Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en) adds a button inside the browser to start it as a separate window. But I don't find a way to start that window without opening a Chrome window. (I use Firefox as default, rarely use Hangouts, don't want it in Firefox, and when I do use it I want only that window, not Chrome's.)

I want a way to start the Hangouts window while Chrome is  **NOT** already running — in background or otherwise (without another Chrome window becoming visible):`chrome-browser` would start of course, but **the Hangouts window should be the only Chrome window**.

I know this would happen with the [Hangouts **App**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl?hl=en) instead of the extension, but that would soon be deprecated it seems, as starting it shows a banner that links to the extension page:

[image]

In all respects the two Hangouts windows (that of the extension and that off the app) look identical - have the same options and *are* the same thing. The only difference is that the extension window cannot be started with a launcher, that is: a **command** within a `.desktop` file. Installing the app creates the file 
`~/.local/share/applications/chrome-knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl-Profile_1.desktop` with the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Google Hangouts
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser "--profile-directory=Default" --app-id=knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl
Icon=chrome-knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl
```

The idea would be to modify the `Exec` line so that it directs to the extension instead of the app. I can get the `id` of the extension: it is the one in the path where that extension is installed: `~.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd`; and I can confirm that with `xprop` applied to the window: `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "crx_nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd", "Chromium-browser"`

But simply replacing that ID would not work: the command `/usr/bin/chromium-browser "--profile-directory=Default" --app-id=nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd` would open the page`chrome://extensions/` instead of the extension window.

It seems **the extension cannot be started with the `--app-id` argument** (although Chrome installs applications and extensions at the same location: `~.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/`.)

The extension-specific argument that I found [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) is `--load-extension`, but that is just meant to specify the extension to be "loaded" (enabled, I imagine) when the browser is started.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround that I will **not mark as the definitive answer**: looking at `chrome-browser --help` I see no options for "extension", but there is this:

```
--app=URL
              Runs URL in "app mode": with no browser toolbars.
```

As there ***is*** a [web page for Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com/?h), one could access that page in Chrome but *without browser toolbars* with the command:

```
google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app=https://hangouts.google.com/?h
```

But this is **not** going to run that extension, and, as it is just a new no-tabs no-toolbars Chrome window, it looks differently too. Some might say it even looks better.

On the other hand, using a web page instead of the extension is far from what is asked above. (I can do that in Firefox, etc).

Comment: I think this a quite fine answer tbh.